# how to use mysql with laravel without any external database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have seen a localhost database like H2Database in java and i was wondering if there any way we can store mysql database in our local host and we don't even have to use external database.

Comment: Just install mysql on your local server?

Comment: is there any way without installing the mysql? i am searching laravel packages like h2database

Comment: [SQLite is supported by laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database)

Comment: development and testing on a other database system then the production database system is asking for trouble **be warned**

Comment: @BackSlash thankyou this is what i was seeking for

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use your local database like MySQL. You need to install MySQL and create the database. Then you can save the database credentials in ".env" file like this -

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=mydbname
DB_USERNAME=mydbuser
DB_PASSWORD=mydbpassword
```

You have to use DB in your controller like this

```
use DB;
```

and then you can use DB::table for your SQL queries. You can also use Laravel DB models.